# Regular expression for 3 different vowels in succession

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches 3 or more **different** vowels in a row.
I understand to write a regular expression search 3 **identical** vowels.

```
/([aeuioy])\\1{2,}/
```

But, about 3 **different**...
any thoughts..

Please help me to solve this problem!
Actually no thoughts in my head.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this cannot be done using a regex

Comment: sure it could! Backreferences work inside character classes and some regex variants support character class subtraction. It just depends on your flavor. OP what flavor of regex do you need?

Comment: hmm..
what about

([aeuioy])((?:(?!\1)(?1)))((?:(?!\2)(?2)))

Comment: Mikhail, your expression looks a bit different than mine but it works the same!

Comment: @Mikhail: Please provide some example to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @AdamSmith:"Backreferences work inside character classes": It's false.

Comment: Must the three vowwels be consecutive or not? Is `abcdefhij` valid or not?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy in question!
Consecutive!

Answer (score 12):

Look for 3 consecutive vowels. Capture the first in a group. After the first, check if it's not #1 again with a Negative Lookahead. Passing that test, capture the next character. Then use *two* Negative Lookahead's, one to check if it's not #1 and the other if it's not #2.

The latter step can be OR'ed into a single lookahead.

```
(?=[aeouiy]{3})(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2).
```

You don't need any test for the last character. The first Lookahead ensures it's one of `aeouiy`; the third, negative, lookahead ensures it's not character #1 or character #2.

Comment: OP wrote **3 or more different vowels in a row** which doesn't mean 3 vowels in a row I believe. (But OP should have provided some examples to clarify)

Answer (score 6):

Not that it's necessarily the most practical option, but this is the only one so far that is an "actual" regular expression:

```
(iea|oea|uea|yea|eia|oia|uia|yia|eoa|ioa|uoa|yoa|eua|iua|oua|yua|eya|iya|oya|uya|iae|oae|uae|yae|aie|oie|uie|yie|aoe|ioe|uoe|yoe|aue|iue|oue|yue|aye|iye|oye|uye|eai|oai|uai|yai|aei|oei|uei|yei|aoi|eoi|uoi|yoi|aui|eui|oui|yui|ayi|eyi|oyi|uyi|eao|iao|uao|yao|aeo|ieo|ueo|yeo|aio|eio|uio|yio|auo|euo|iuo|yuo|ayo|eyo|iyo|uyo|eau|iau|oau|yau|aeu|ieu|oeu|yeu|aiu|eiu|oiu|yiu|aou|eou|iou|you|ayu|eyu|iyu|oyu|eay|iay|oay|uay|aey|iey|oey|uey|aiy|eiy|oiy|uiy|aoy|eoy|ioy|uoy|auy|euy|iuy|ouy)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?:[^aeiou]*([aeiou])(?!.*?\1)){3}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tI4jF7/1)

**Update:** In case OP is looking for **at least three consecutive different vowels in each line** then use this simpler version of above regex:

```
(?:([aeiou])(?!.{1,2}\1)){3}
```

#### [New RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tI4jF7/4)

Comment: I downvoted this originally because I thought it would pass `aXXXeXXXa` but it doesn't. I still don't know HOW it doesn't, but it doesn't. That said I think OP was looking to match `aei` and not `aXXXeXXXi`, but it is rather ambiguous.

Comment: Yes some examples from OP would have been good for clarification. I interpreted it as if any input line with at least 3 different vowels is a match.

Comment: @anubhava The OP uses the phrase "in a row", an idiom in English that means "in a series without interruption".

Comment: @trooper: Thanks for your comment. `row` can be interpreted as one line also. Having said that my regex would still work for that requirement also as [you can see from this demo](http://regex101.com/r/tI4jF7/2)

Answer (score 1):

Any thing that you want is all **permutation** between vowels ,so you can use this :

```
(?=[aeouiy]{3}$)(?!.*(.).*\1).*$
```

`(?!.*(.).*\1)` is for ensures that you can't match a repeated character !